# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-manager

```
it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL
WARNING: Native library load failed.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path*
WARNING: Native library load failed.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdalalljni in java.library.path
```

I'm trying to run a GeoServer docker image in a Kubernates pod. Application is starting up but throwing above error. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

That is a warning not an error, providing you are not trying to use the gdal plugin there's no problem. If you are trying to use the gdal plugin you need to make sure you have followed the instructions exactly including setting the location of the gdal jni library correctly.